# zipping files in python without folder structure

Tags: python, zip

I want to create a zip file of some files somewhere on the disk in python. I successfully got the path to the folder and each file name so I did:

```py
with zp(os.path.join(self.savePath, self.selectedIndex + ".zip"), "w") as zip:
                for file in filesToZip:
                    zip.write(self.folderPath + file)
```

Everything works fine, but the zipfile that is output contains the entire folder structure leading up to the files. Is there a way to only zip the files and not the folders with it?

Comment: My approach is to create a list with the files names you want to zip (files inside the folder you mentioned) then zip them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write):

> ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None,
> compresslevel=None)
>
> Write the file named **filename** to the archive, giving it the archive
> name **arcname** (by default, this will be the same as filename, but
> without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed).

So, just specify an explicit `arcname`:

```
with zp(os.path.join(self.savePath, self.selectedIndex + ".zip"), "w") as zip:
                for file in filesToZip:
                    zip.write(self.folderPath + file, arcname=file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I' misunderstand the question but could someone explain to me why the answer is not:

```
zip.write(file, arcname=os.path.basename(file))
```

It works for me but, again, I might be missing something in the question...